# What's the best practice for developing AJAX apps locally and deploying them on the fly?

Tags: javascript, ajax, same-origin-policy

I'm new to AJAX development. Due to same-origin policy, the most inconvenient thing for me so far is to modify the host information string (such as absolute URLs) in JavaScript files every time whenever I try to deploy the local files to the remote. I thought about writing a shell script for doing this but it seems awkward and not flexible. What's the best practice for doing this?

EDIT:

What if I wanna debug the remote AJAX app instead?

Comment: Only use absolute URLs without host information? E.g. `/path/to/endpoint`. Or what are you talking about?

Comment: @FelixKling Maybe I didn't make my question very clear. Actually I did use absolute URLs, and that's the problem -- I have to change something like "localhost" to "xxx.com" whenever I deploy the files.

Comment: If your URL does not contain a host (e.g. `/path/to/endpoint`) then there is nothing you have to change. I guess you should provide a concrete example.

Comment: @FelixKling Oh. That works. Sorry for a stupid question...

Comment: @FelixKling What if I wanna debug a remote AJAX app?

Comment: if you could use something like requirejs, or just load the scripts with a simple loader script, you can code a path into a variable so that it would only need to be changed in one place. you can also use a small config file, one you can modify on each end, and never re-adjust.

Comment: @dandavis Uhmm...sounds nice.

Answer (score 0):

Add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header to your response. It's depends on what backend or server side you are using. There are some reference:

1. [HTTP Access Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)
2. [Enable CORS in Apache](http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html)
3. [Website about "enable cross-origin resource sharing"](http://enable-cors.org/)

Comment: Could you please be more specific?

Comment: Your question is changed, my reference is for enabling CORS.

Explain your application's specification first. What's your backend server/ web server? Is it Apache with PHP, NodeJS, Java/ Scala with PlayFramework/ Netty or Tomcat? Also what is your client side that consume your data? Is it WebApps with Javascript, Native Android apps, Native iOS apps, or what?

Comment: Server end is Tomcat, client side is webapps with JavaScript.